Apache2.4 adding spurious double-slash in executing ProxyPass directive
I have this ProxyPass directive on my Windows server at 172.16.1.1 which is running Apache 2.4 as a Windows service:
ProxyPass / http://app.123.com/ retry=3 acquire=3000 timeout=600 keepalive=on
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.123.com/

I need to be able to access "app.123.com" and all its sub-locations on 172.16.1.1 transparently, e. g. in Firfox / Chrome / Edge in Windows do
172.16.1.1/auth/login

on my local Windows server and have Apache on that server proxy and proxyreverse this URI to
app.123.com/auth/login

in the background, for all sub-locations of the domain.
E.g. with my browser address bar showing "172.16.1.1/auth/login" the page content needs to come from "app.123.com/auth/login" and so on for all the sub-locations on that domain.
However, if I use the above ProxyPass directive, with Apache 2.4 on Windows, this
172.16.1.1/auth/login

gets proxied as
app.123.com//auth/login

E. g. Apache apparently doubles the slash - this breaks "app.123.com" and nothing works.
I have tried doing this:
ProxyPass / http://app.123.com retry=3 acquire=3000 timeout=600 keepalive=on
ProxyPassReverse / http://app.123.com

e. g. remove the trailing slashes, but this results in
app.123.comauth/login

being referenced by the Apache on 172.16.1.1.
Any idea how I can fix this - if I add a slash to the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, it becomes
app.123.com//auth/login

when proxied, if I remove the slash from the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse it becomes
app.123.comauth/login

if proxied.
What gives?
I just need
app.123.com/auth/login
to be proxied - no messing with the slash after the domain name...
Thanks!
